# Structure of declarations in C++ The C++ Prog. Lang 4th edition by Bjarne page 153/154

Tags: c++

I am studying The C++ Prog. Lang 4th edition by Bjarne. In chapter 6, section 6.3.1 page 153 and 154, i found a couple of statements contradicting each other.

On page 153 under section 6.3.1 in says **A declarator optionally including a name**

But then on page 154 it says.

**A declarator is composed of a name and optionally some declarator operators**

can anyone please clarify what does it mean ? does it mean both name and declarator operators are optional ? below are the snippets from page 153 and 154.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some context for the quote for those of us who don't own the book?

Comment: Does the book have examples too? (I don't have my copy to hand - it's far to heavy to carry round) (Some examples might help us explain better; you don't always need variable names in function protoypes for example)

Comment: bjarnes book are not authorative for the language, it wouldnt be the first time that he is sloppy for the sake of explaining stuff. Not saying that it is wrong, but maybe its just due to context that the two statements are not saying identical things

Comment: I just added snippets from the book showing both statements.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the book at hand, but there two different "types" of declarators. There is the usual declarator:

```
int a;
//  ^
```

Here, as Bjarne says, the name is not optional. But then there is something called an abstract declarator, which is used for function parameters:

```
void f(int a, int);
//               ^ name optional
```

Which is what the first quote is referring to.

Comment: Should be nice to have a working crystal ball :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have context for your quotes, but Bjarne is likely simplifying in one or both cases.

This is what the standard says of effects of a declaration:

> A declaration (Clause 7) **may** introduce one or more names into a translation unit or redeclare names introduced by previous declarations.

The first paragraph of the Declarations clause:

> Declarations **generally** specify how names are to be interpreted.

There are many different types of declarations; too many to list them all here. *Most* of them declare a name or several. Here is an example of a declaration which does not declare a name:

```
 ;
```

It is called the empty-declaration. Clearly, this declaration has neither optional nor required declarators or specifiers.